# Start process an keep window on top [WPF]

Tags: wpf, process, window

my WPF App starts another .exe with

```
processtempexe.Start(tempexe);
processtempexe.WaitForExit();
```

now i got the problem that my WPF app is overlaping the recent started tempexe and i dont have the chance to get it on top of my WPF app to actually use it. How can i re-activate my started temp.exe. Is there a solution, please help?

thanks for every thought :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could minimize the WPF window in between those calls.

Comment: cant do this, my WPF app is fullscreen whitout a visible taskbar an the user has no mouse or keyboard(-> Touchscreen)

Comment: Have a look at these api calls: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186431 You will have to use PInvoke but FindWindow and BringWindowToTop might do the trick